# Pig script not working using Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-pig, emr, amazon-emr

I cannot get this script to work:

```
raw = LOAD 's3://xxxxxxxxx/*' AS (name:chararray, year:float, occurrences:float, books:float);
B = GROUP raw BY name;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE B.name, (SUM(B.occurrences) / SUM(B.books)) AS average;
D = ORDER C BY average DESC;
E = LIMIT D 10;
STORE E INTO 's3://xxxxxx';
```

Comment: what is the problem you faced

Answer (score 0):

The statement `C` is not right, you can't access the variable `name,occurrences and books` using `Relation B`. This should be accessible only by `relation raw`. Can you change your `stmt C` something like this?

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group, SUM(raw.occurrences)/SUM(raw.books) AS average;
```

here `group` refer to variable `name`

If you face any other issues, please paste your error logs.